# How to read the environment variable from maven command line and choose correct properties file

Tags: java, maven, properties-file, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to run maven command to execute some tests based on environment like mvn test -env=qa

This properties file has some common variables for all environments

```
resource/application.properties
message = .......
loadPath = .....
```

This is a class to read the properties

```
public class PropertyFile {

    private static Properties prop;

    private static void getPropertyFile() {
        String propFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/application.properties";
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(propFilePath)) {
            prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        if (prop == null) {
            getPropertyFile();
        }
        return prop.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

So now I want to create another two files

```
qa.properties
baseurl=http://qa.....
```

and

```
dev.properties
baseurl=http://dev....
```

When I run mvn test -env=qa. It will pass this qa variable and read application.properties for common properties and read qa.properties for specific environment properties.

I did some research to add the variables to pom file

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <env>qa</env>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But not sure how to properly configure this. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: I can strongly recommend to follow the suggestions of Nick Holt...

Answer (score 0):

First, this sounds like a bad idea to me - your build should be portable and environment agnostic.  How is another developer going to know about the magic parameters to pass to the build?

Also unit tests (which is what the `test` phase should be running) should be local to the machine running the build, typically one unit test class testing one actual class.  Unit tests should be run a lot and placing external dependencies in them is a prime cause of this not happening (because it make them too slow).

So with these warnings, to make the above work you can pass environment variables to maven via the command line simply by specifying a `-D` system property like you would with the `jvm`, for example:

```
mvn clean test -Denv=dev
```

Would set a system property called `env` with a value `dev`.

To use this in your code, you need to know that the `resources` directories are available via the classpath when running in Maven (`test/resources` is only visible from the tests I believe).  This means that, unless you're doing something funky, you can get the `InputStream` for the properties file from the `ClassLoader`, like this:

```
//Get the environment, defaulting to dev if none is specified.
String environment = System.getProperty("env", "dev"); 

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("application-" + environment + ".properties"));
```